# How can I create RequiredFieldValidattion in Android?

Tags: java, android

Here this is my code. It looks a bit complicated but it's working all fine. I just want to know how can I create when I click btnCreateProduct it should validate required edit text field and where to add those code?

```
package com.prinsapps.whatson;


import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.prinsapps.whatson.Addevent.CreateNewProduct;



public class Addevent extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private ImageButton ib;
  private Calendar cal;
  private int day;
  private int month;
  private int year;
  private EditText et;

//Progress Dialog
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  EditText inputName;
  EditText inputDesc;
  EditText inputCountry;
  EditText inputdate;
  EditText inputLink;
  EditText inputOrg;
// url to create new product
  private static String url_create_product = "http://-----------";

// JSON Node names
  private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.add_event);

//Edit Text
  inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
  inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
  inputCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCountry);
  inputdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputdate);
  inputLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLink);
  inputOrg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputOrg);

// mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_button);
  ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
  cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputdate);
      ib.setOnClickListener(this);

// Create button
  Button btnCreateProduct = (Button)  
  findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

// button click event
  btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
}


@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  showDialog(0);
  }

@Override
@Deprecated
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
}

  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
  int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
  et.setText(selectedYear+"/"+(selectedMonth+1)+"/"+selectedDay);
}
};

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
  class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Addevent.this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(true);
          pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * 
     * */
      protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
          String name = inputName.getText().toString();
          String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
          String country = inputCountry.getText().toString();
          String date = inputdate.getText().toString();
          String link = inputLink.getText().toString();
          String org = inputOrg.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
          List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", country));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("link", link));
          params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("org", org));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
  }
```

Comment: can you explain your question better?

Comment: Hi nikis the question was how can i implement the  require field validation when click Button (acording to my following code button is btnCreateProduct), and where to add those codes

Answer (score 1):

use editText watcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
//Add your validations here
            }
        });
```

Comment: But that would be called everytime somebody tipes into the textfield. That means it will consume much computing time

Answer (score 1):

Yes it working fine now

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (  ( !inputName.getText().toString().equals("")) && 
              ( !inputDesc.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
              ( !inputCountry.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
              ( !inputdate.getText().toString().equals(""))
            )
        {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
        else if ( ( !inputName.getText().toString().equals("")) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Enter Event Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if ( ( !inputDesc.getText().toString().equals("")) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Enter Event Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if ( ( !inputCountry.getText().toString().equals("")) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Enter Place or Country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if ( ( !inputdate.getText().toString().equals("")) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Select Date When Event Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Event Details are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm assuming, that you don't want to get empty your Textfield empty if you creating a product, I'd suggest to check wether the `Strings` of your `EditTexts` are null or empty.

This could look like this:

```
if(inputName.getText().equals("") || inputName.getText().equals(null)){
//Maybe show some message, that the given field ist required to be filled out
}
```

I would suggest to add this into your `onClick()` Method, or write an extra method to check wether an EditText is empty and return a boolean value. This could look like this:

```
public boolean notEmpty(EditText et){
if(et.getText().equals("") || et.getText().equals(null)){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

And then check this for every `EditText` et before you create a new product.